# Admob Interstitial ads shows up only once in the App

Tags: android, admob

I am designing an app where the user clicks a button and the interstitial ads get displayed. 
On closing the ad, the counter gets added to one, it gets displayed. 
Basically, it is to notify the users how many ads they have watched. 
But the counter doesn't get added and the ads aren't getting updated.
Here is the code:-

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private Button watchButton;
int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //TextView tv_data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.disCount);
    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            count++;
            TextView tv_data=findViewById(R.id.disCount);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tv_data.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            // Load the next interstitial.

        }

    });
    watchButton = findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    watchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Listen for when user presses button
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If a interstitial is ready, show it
            if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();

            }
            else
            {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
            // Otherwise end this activity (go back to first activity)
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting a break-point inside onAdClosed? does it execute?

Comment: Pardon me, This is my first app, So dunno what you are trying to say. Is it interstitial.destroy() you are mentioning about?.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/25080822/8711985] . This might help